# Regular expression for extracting an IP address from a string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, ip-address

I am dealing with a table called `ipaddr` with a column called destination and have entries in the column that look like and are of type `varchar`

```
tunnel://169.96.88.11:80/
url://169.96.88.30
169.96.88.59:443
```

These are all possibilities. I want to write a regex statement that returns true when it just matches the first three octets of the IP and nothing more. So, all three examples above match `169.96.88`.

How do you write a regular expression so that I select rows in the table based on a specific ip address subnet?

```
select * from ipaddr where destination like '%169.96.88%'
```

That is, I am tying to collect all records that have a destination entry in the `169.96.88.*` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   ipaddr 
WHERE  destination ~ '(://|^)169\.96\.88\.[0-9]';
```

The pattern starts at the beginning of the string or with `://`.
Then follows the network, a dot and at least one more digit.

Tested with PostgreSQL 9.1.4. Note that I use the now default [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS). Else you have to write:

```
WHERE  destination ~ E'(://|^)169\\.96\\.88\\.[0-9]';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tunnel://\(\([[:digit:]]\{1,3\}[.]\)\{4\}\):80/ -> \2
```

This regular expression extracts the IP, and returns it as \2.

Depending on the software you are using, you use this regexp with minor changes '->' means 'return'.

Comment: actually there many different character options before and after the ip entry for example  url://169.96.88.11:443 is valid or 169.96.88.11:80 or http://169.96.88.11 is all possibilities how do I write a regex that ignores the first characters up into the first number?

Comment: If there are many possibilities in place of 'tunnel', you replace 'tunnel' with \\(tunnel|url|OTHER_STR\\), but in this case you replace the final \2 with \3